# How to start remotely process in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, remoting, invoke-command, start-process

I have a problem, I have a *script* which:

- Connect with PSSession (I use `PSSession` with admin account)
- Stop 2 process
- Do change on them files
- Start the 2 process (Problem here)

I want to start process on server, so i'm connect with PSSession (No problem)

I do Invoke-Command :

```
# $pathProg path to my program
Invoke-Command -session $mySession -command {Start-Process $($args[0])} -ArgumentList $pathProg
```

But it does nothing (I verify with VNC)

I do Invoke-Command too :

```
# $pathProg path to my program
Invoke-Command -session $mySession -command {&$($args[0])} -ArgumentList $pathProg
```

It lauch the program (Good) but my script wait the end program (Not good)

Anyone have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try using WMI:

```
$command = "notepad.exe"
$process = [WMICLASS]"\\$CompName\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process"
$result = $process.Create($command)
```

If you need passing credentials:

```
$cred = get-credential
$process = get-wmiobject -query "SELECT * FROM Meta_Class WHERE __Class = 'Win32_Process'" -namespace "root\cimv2" -computername $CompName -credential $cred
$results = $process.Create( "notepad.exe" )
```

Comment: Thanks !!! +1 :D
I think that is the "version bourrin" (in French ^^) but it works !

Comment: Le cheval ou la femme facile? ;) C'est un plaisir aider!

Comment: But there's no GUI, how to display the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

`$pathProg` may be not be available within the script block which gets run eventually. You might want to pass it as an argument to the script block

```
Invoke-Command -session $mySession -command { param($progPath) ... } -argumentlist $progPath
```

Not that the outer `-argumentlist`, passes the arguments to the scriptblock.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building the command as a string locally, then passing it to the Invoke-Command script as a ScriptBlock?

```
$remoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'MyServer'
$processName = 'MyProcess'

$command = 'Start-Service ' + $processName + ';'

Invoke-Command -Session      $remoteSession `
               -ScriptBlock  ([ScriptBlock]::create($command))

Remove-PSSession $remoteSession
```

If you want feedback from the remote server then you can get the output via Write-Output, like this:

```
$command = 'Start-Service ' + $processName + ' | Write-Output ;'
```