# Can't get the entire OutputStream of the process which runs bat remotely via psxec

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, psexec

Goal: Running bat files remotely for test needs.

Requirements:

Waiting till the operation succeeds.

Getting the result code and using it.

Logging all the output.

Situation:

I am running my code as java application on Windows 7. The application creates the process which runs cmd.exe to run bat from the local machine. The bat file contains a command for **psexec** to run another bat file remotely.

I have tried other ways without creating local bat file: tried to run psexec command, but failed to pass more than 1 argument.

Listing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException
{       
    String[] command = { "cmd", };
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
    new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
    PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
    stdin.println("cd C:\\Autotests\\Bat\\");
    stdin.println(".\\localBat.bat");
    // write any other commands you want here
    stdin.close();
    int returnCode = p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);

}

public static class SyncPipe implements Runnable
{
    public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm)
    {
        istrm_ = istrm;
        ostrm_ = ostrm;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            for (int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1;)
            {
                ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final OutputStream  ostrm_;
    private final InputStream   istrm_;
}
```

Contents of localBat.bat:

```
C:\\PSTools\\psexec.exe \\**.**.**.** -s -u domain\user -p password C:\somepath\remoteBat.bat
```

**What's the problem?**

If I run the localBat.bat manually from the command line I get all the output of the remoteBat.bat displayed in the console. But when I run my application, the remoteBat.bat runs, I get the exit code stroed but I don't get the entire output, only these lines:

```
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
Connecting to **.**.**.**...
Starting PSEXESVC service on **.**.**.**...
Connecting with PsExec service on **.**.**.**...
Starting C:\somepath\remoteBat.bat on **.**.**.**...
C:\somepath\remoteBat.bat exited on **.**.**.** with error code 0.
```

Impact

I can't handle and analyze the situation when the exit code is different from 0.

Please, help me, I'm stuck here.

Comment: this is known issue - http://forum.sysinternals.com/faq-common-pstools-issues_topic15920.html  . To execute a command on a remote script and get the output you can use WMIC or xcmd  - > http://feldkir.ch/xcmd.htm

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will check WMIC. I have tried using xcmd firstly, but it did not work for me.

Comment: have on mind that xcmd does not work against localhost.Check also this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182690/how-to-start-remotely-process-in-powershell

Comment: It's over comlicated for me ( i don't have enough ti,e to learn using WMI.

Comment: I have found a work-around: the batch file on remote machine rights its output to a shared folder so that I can simply read it in my application.