# Setting Power Plan on multiple server using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I want to set "High Performance" powerplan on multiple server machines. I've the following script which is running fine when I execute this on the servers one by one.

> Set-PowerPlan "High performance"

```
function Set-PowerPlan {

[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $True)]

param (

    [ValidateSet("High performance", "Balanced", "Power saver")]

    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]

    [string] $PreferredPlan = "High Performance"
      )

Write-Host "Setting power plan to `"$PreferredPlan`""

$guid = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PowerPlan -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Filter "ElementName='$PreferredPlan'").InstanceID.ToString()

$regex = [regex]"{(.*?)}$"

$plan = $regex.Match($guid).groups[1].value

powercfg -S $plan

$Output = "Power plan set to "

$Output += "`"" + ((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PowerPlan -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Filter "IsActive='$True'").ElementName) + "`""

 Write-Host $Output
}
```

How to pass a list of servers to this script so that the power plan is set on all servers recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the computername parameter to your function and `Get-WmiObject` inside it. Also I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183375/3711461) to launch process remotely.

```
function Set-PowerPlan {

    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $True)]
    param (

        [ValidateSet("High performance", "Balanced", "Power saver")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$PreferredPlan = "High Performance",
        [string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    Write-Host "Setting power plan to `"$PreferredPlan`""

    $guid = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PowerPlan -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Filter "ElementName='$PreferredPlan'" -ComputerName $ComputerName).InstanceID.ToString()

    $regex = [regex]"{(.*?)}$"

    $plan = $regex.Match($guid).groups[1].value

    #powercfg -S $plan
    $process = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Meta_Class WHERE __Class = 'Win32_Process'" -Namespace "root\cimv2" -ComputerName $ComputerName
    $results = $process.Create("powercfg -S $plan")

    $Output = "Power plan set to "
    $Output += "`"" + ((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PowerPlan -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Filter "IsActive='$True'" -ComputerName $ComputerName).ElementName) + "`""

    Write-Host $Output
}

$ServerList = @(
    'CompName1',
    'Compname2'
)

foreach ($server in $ServerList ) {
    Set-PowerPlan -PreferredPlan 'High performance' -ComputerName $comp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make changes to the script as suggested below:

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $True)]
param (

    [ValidateSet("High performance", "Balanced", "Power saver")]

    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]

    [string] $PreferredPlan = "High Performance"
      )

Write-Host "Setting power plan to `"$PreferredPlan`""

$guid = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PowerPlan -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Filter "ElementName='$PreferredPlan'").InstanceID.ToString()

$regex = [regex]"{(.*?)}$"

$plan = $regex.Match($guid).groups[1].value

powercfg -S $plan

$Output = "Power plan set to "

$Output += "`"" + ((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PowerPlan -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Filter "IsActive='$True'").ElementName) + "`""

 Write-Host $Output
```

And use this command to target multiple servers:

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath .\Set-PowerPlan.ps1 -ComputerName (Get-Content -Path C:\temp\computers.txt)
```

Where Computers.txt will have server names separated by new line character.